# Get Hostname during tomcat-application deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, environment-variables, hostname

I have a task to use hostname in Spring-database-configuration.

For example, when app deployed on localhost db-requests to be send at localhost:5432/database,  othewise - on (for example) 172.18.0.2:5432/database.

I'am trying to use Spring SpEL for this purpose:

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
      p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      p:url="#{'jdbc:postgresql://' + @bUrl.getHost=='localhost'?'localhost':'172.18.0.2' + ':5432/infostock'}"
       />
```

In this expression I need to identify bUrl.  It must containt info about hostname.

But how could I get this info:

```
 <bean class="java.net.URI" id="bUrl">
    <constructor-arg value="${???????}"/>
</bean>
```

Is there are special variables?

I tried to get hostname from HttpServletRequest, but the problem is that application able to fullfill requests after stage of deploying.

Comment: the requirement is to get the hostname dynamically or read from a properties file ?

Comment: dynamically - depends on hostname (localhost or other)

Comment: I do not know how to do it dynamically . Another approach will be to define two `dataSource` beans associated with two profiles ( say dev and prod ) and use command line argument ( example , `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"` )